# Arithmetic calculator using a stack (error)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an arithmetic calculator using an `ArrayStack`. The way it works, is that it takes a `txt` file that has a bunch of expressions, and it scans through each line. For every line it scans, it copies the expression, as well as its result, and pastes both to an output `txt` file.

For the actual calculation, it uses 2 `stacks`; one to hold values, and one to hold operators. As it scans through an expression, it pushes values in the value stack, and operators in the operator stack.

Every time it pushes an op in the operator stack that has a higher precedence than the current top op in the stack, it will pop the current op, as well as pop the top 2 values in the value stack, perform the calculation, and push back the result in the value stack. This keeps running until it detects a `$` in the input `txt` file.

The problem: when I run the program, I get following exception:

> "Invalid Operator!"

I don't understand the issue.

**Expressions.txt:**

```
3 + 5

4 + 6

6 + 7

$
```

**Out.txt (what it should have):**

```
3 + 5  

8

4 + 6

10

6 + 7

13
```

`Out.txt` always remains empty. What exactly is the invalid operator?

Here is my code:

```
package firstcalc;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FirstCalc
{
    public interface Stack<E>
    {
        int size();
        boolean isEmpty();
        void push(E e);
        E top();
        E pop();
    }

    public static class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E>
    {
        public static final int CAPACITY = 100;
        private E[] data;
        private int t = -1;
        public ArrayStack()
        {
            this(CAPACITY);
        }
        public ArrayStack(int capacity)
        {
            data = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
        }

        public int size()
        {
            return (t + 1);
        }

        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return (t == -1);
        }

        public void push(E e) throws IllegalStateException
        {
            if (size() == data.length) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is full!");
            data[++t] = e;
        }

        public E top()
        {
            if (isEmpty()) return null;
            return data[t];
        }

        public E pop()
        {
            if (isEmpty()) return null;
            E answer = data[t];
            data[t] = null;
            t--;
            return answer;
        }
}

static ArrayStack valStk = new ArrayStack<>();
static ArrayStack opStk = new ArrayStack<>();
static int x;
static int y;
static String op;

public static void doOp()
{
    x = (int) valStk.pop();
    y = (int) valStk.pop();
    op = (String) opStk.pop();
    valStk.push(y);
    valStk.push(op);
    valStk.push(x);
}

public static void repeatOps (String refOp)
{
    while (valStk.size() > 1 && (prec(refOp) <= prec(opStk.top().toString())))
    {
                doOp();
    }
}

public static int prec(String op)
{
    switch(op)
    {
        case "(":
        case ")":
            return 1;
        case "!":
            return 2;
        case "^":
            return 3;
        case "*":
        case "/":
            return 4;
        case "+":
        case "-":
            return 5;
        case ">":
        case ">=":
        case "<":
        case "<=":
            return 6;
        case "==":
        case "!=":
            return 7;
        case "$":
            return 8;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Operator!");
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String str = "";
    String line = "";
    try
    {
                File file = new File("expressions.txt");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("out.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
                line = sc.nextLine();

                while(!line.equals("$"))
                {
                    pw.println("Expression: " + line);
                    line = line.replaceAll(" ", "");

                    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
                    {
                        char c = line.charAt(i);
                        if(Character.isDigit(c))
                        {
                            valStk.push(c);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if((c == '>' || c == '<' || c == '!' || c == '=') && (line.charAt(i + 1) == '='))
                            {
                                sb.append(c);
                                sb.append(line.charAt(i + 1));
                                str = sb.toString();
                                repeatOps(str);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.append(c);
                                str = sb.toString();
                                repeatOps(str);
                            }
                            opStk.push(c);
                        }
                    }
                    pw.println(valStk.top());
                    line = sc.nextLine();
                }
                pw.close();
    }

    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: a simple way to know would be to change your exception throwing to `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Operator " + op);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code snippet, you keep on appending new characters to your `StringBuilder` which will likely to send `Strings` like `>=<=` and `>=<=>=` etc. as your `while` loop progresses further.

```
if((c == '>' || c == '<' || c == '!' || c == '=') && (line.charAt(i + 1) == '='))
{
    sb.append(c);
    sb.append(line.charAt(i + 1));
    str = sb.toString();
    repeatOps(str);
}
else
{
    sb.append(c);
    str = sb.toString();
    repeatOps(str);
}
```

Since these newly created `Strings` are not defined in any of the cases in your `switch` it goes to the `default` and prints the `Exception`.

What you should be doing instead is create a new `StringBuilder` instance every time.

For Example,

```
if((c == '>' || c == '<' || c == '!' || c == '=') && (line.charAt(i + 1) == '='))
{
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(c);
    sb.append(line.charAt(i + 1));
    repeatOps(sb.toString());
}
else
{
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(c);
    repeatOps(sb.toString());
}
```